# Converting one-dimensional array with multi-dimensional values to just multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, deep-learning

I am working with images in deep learning and I have a multi-dimensional Python array declared by this:

`train_images = temp1.apply(format_image).values`

When I execute this code:

`print(train_images[0])`

I get the 3-dimensional array of RGB values.

When I execute this code:

`print(train_images[0].shape)`

it gives (224, 224, 3)

and when I execute this:

```
print(train_images[0].shape)
```

I get (1547,)

I believe I need it to have the size (1547,224,224,3) for the machine learning algorithm to work. I have definitely encountered this before but don't remember how I fixed it, any ideas?

Comment: Please mention the value you have specified as the input_shape in the first layer of your DL model

Comment: @vbhargav875 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    efn.EfficientNetB7(
        input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
        weights='imagenet',
        include_top=False
    ),
    L.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    L.Dense(train_labels.shape[1], activation='softmax')
])

Answer (score 0):

If all of your images have same shape, you can jsut use `reshape`

```
import numpy as np

train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (train_images[0], 224, 224, 3))
```